# How to open a TOD video files in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, video, conversion

When I record with JVC camera, I get `.MOI` and `.TOD` files for videos. How to open these files in my Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Comment: Have you tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) or [MPlayer OS X Extended](http://www.mplayerosx.ch/)? (untested, have never seen those file formats)

Comment: Which camera model is it?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [MOI Converter for Mac](http://www.modconverterformac.net/moi-converter-for-mac.htm).

(But as you might have noticed, it's some funny looking shareware, so, there's that..)

And here's [another blog post dealing with this topic](http://www.aimersoft-mac.com/articles/how-to-convert-mod-moi-tod-to-avi-on-mac.html), also featuring some software.